# ElasticSearch Query, match a certain term and count given a date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I feel like this shouldn't be as difficult as its turning out to be, I've been attempting to use the:

```
index/_search
```

and

```
index/_count
```

endpoints, using query, bool, must filter etc.  It seems no matter how I construct it, I cannot use range and date, with the match filter.  The elasticsearch documentation doesn't seem to show complex queries like this so I'm not exactly sure how to construct it.  The main query I've been manipulating is:

```
{
     "query":{
          "bool":{
               "must":{
                    "range":{
                        "date":{
                             "gte":"now-1d/d",
                             "lt" :"now/d"
                               }
                             },
                    "match":{
                         "KEY":"VALUE"
                          }
                 }
           }
     }
 }
```

I either get "no query registered for date", or "unknown key for a start_object in match"  Been all over stackoverflow and can't seem to find an answer to this, it seems like it should be quite a simple query to make against a data store such as this.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide sample index data that you are trying to find, concrete query and its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must can take an array of conditions if you want to combine them. Try this format :

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "gte": "now-1d/d",
                        "lt": "now/d"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "match": { "KEY": "VALUE" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: That did it! Thanks!